# How to chain conditional queries in Android Studio (Java) with Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write a query with conditional chained `whereEqualTo()` methods.

I tried doing something like this;

```java
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference colRef = db.collection("collection");

if (!filter.isEmpty() && !filter.equals("All")) {
   colRef.whereEqualTo("tag", filter);
}

if (userId != null) {
   colRef.whereEqualTo("user_id", userId);
}

colRef.get();
```

If the filter is equal to "ABC", then I should receive data with `tag` of "ABC" but all data is still being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore queries are immutable, which means that you cannot change the properties of an existing query. If you change the value by calling `.whereEqualTo("tag", filter)`, it becomes a new query.

So to solve this issue, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query colRef = db.collection("collection");
//

if (!filter.isEmpty() && !filter.equals("All")) {
   colRef = colRef.whereEqualTo("tag", filter);
   //
}

if (userId != null) {
   colRef = colRef.whereEqualTo("user_id", userId);
   //
}

colRef.get();
```